# Does adding join condition on two different tables (excluding the table to be joined) slows down query and performance

Tags: mysql, database, database-performance

I have 3 tables in mySQL => table1, table2 and table3 and the data in all three tables is large (>100k)
My join condition is :

```
select * from table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1
join table3 t3 on t3.col2 = t2.col2 and t3.col3 = t1.col3
```

This query renders result very slow and according to me the issue is in the second join condition as if I remove the second condition, the query renders result instantly.
Can anyone please explain the reason of the query being slow?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the execution plan. Slowness may be because you don't have indexes on the joined columns or existing indexes are not being used. Also, avoid `SELECT *` unless you really need all columns from all tables referenced by the query.

Comment: Also, remove the `mysql` tag from your question unless you are actually using MySQL instead of Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Please don't use Indian words like "lakh" here. That will just confuse people.

Comment: I do have indexes on the joined columns but they are not getting used..the solution to this which I found is to forcefully use the index using the USE/FORCE  index syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have these indexes?

```
table2:  (col1)
table3:  (col2, col3) -- in either order
```

Another tip:  Don't use `*` (as in `SELECT *`) unless you really need all the columns.  It prevents certain optimizations.  If you want to discuss this further, please provide the real query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

If any of the columns used for joining are not the same datatype, character set, and collation, then indexes *may* not be useful.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`; it will give some clues we can discuss.

How many rows in the resultset?  Sounds like over 100K?  If so, then perhaps the network transfer time is the real slowdown?

Answer (score 0):

Since the second join is over both tables (two joins) it creates more checks on evaluation. This is creating a triangle rather than a long joined line. 
Also, since all three tables have ~100K lines, even with clustered index on the given columns, it's bound to have a performance hit, also due to all columns being retrieved.
At least, have the select statement as T1.col1, T1.col2...,T2.col1... and so on.
Also have distinct indexes on all columns used in join condition.

More so, do you really want a huge join *without* a where clause? Try adding restrictive conditions for each table and see the magic as it first filters out the available set of results from each table (100k may become 10k) and then the join is attempted.

Also check  SQL Profiler output to see if a TABLE SCAN is being used (most probably yes), if so, having an INDEX SCAN should improve the situation.